# Password confirmation doesnot match?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-6

I am trying to using confirm password validation. I applied correct rules. But when it validates then it give me validation error like below:
The password confirmation does not match.
**Controller**

```
public function register(Request $req){
        $this->validate($req,[
           'Password'         =>   'required|confirmed|min:3'
          ]);

    }
```

Comment: are you sure you sent password_confirmation inside your request

Comment: Please show what data are you sending to this route. ($req->all())

Comment: if password_confirmation must match password, then it must also have the same validation.

Comment: you need `password_confirmation`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

what is your password confirmation field name because |confirmed| always work with laravel naming conversions For example, if the field under validation is password, a matching password_confirmation field must be present in the input.

is that your input name is password_confirmation ??
if not do that 
else comment me more code please so i can help you..

Comment: Thank you. solved. but kindly clear me that  i used same name but the difference was that i used capital P and C like Password_Confirmation. Was this the problem?